# Making a query more efficient

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have the following SQL query

```
SELECT id, name, title, description, time
  FROM entity
  WHERE UNIXTIMESTAMP(CONCAT(date_end, time_end)) > UNIXTIMESTAMP(NOW())
    AND UNIXTIMESTAMP(CONCAT(next_date, next_time)) < UNIXTIMESTAMP(NOW())
```

I was looking into views and other ways to make that query more efficient. The problem is if I have over 10,000 entities to process; then the query will prob take a long time.

What does MySQL provide as tools to make the query above more efficient?

Comment: Have you considered refactoring database table and use `DATETIME` field type? Or even better, `BIGINT` to store raw Unix timestamp?

Comment: What are the datatypes of `date_end`, `time_end`, etc?

Comment: and what column(s) are / is your index(es) on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're just after general techniques, there are already SO questions on the topic, not to mention the MySQL manual section on [optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimization.html).

If you're after specific recommendations for your query, note that MySQL can't apply indices if a column is passed through a function. You'll need to get rid of the `UNIXTIMESTAMP` and `CONCAT` calls around the *_end and next_* columns. One approach would be to change the table schema: combine the columns into "end" and "next" columns of type `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`. Another would be to separate the current time into a date and time, and use that to compare to the columns separately.

Answer (score 2):

Your query will be fine with only 10k records to process but this should be more efficient as it does not involve any type conversions -

```
SELECT id, name, title, description, time 
FROM entity 
WHERE (date_end > CURRENT_DATE OR (date_end = CURRENT_DATE AND time_end >= CURRENT_TIME))
AND (next_date < CURRENT_DATE OR (next_date = CURRENT_DATE AND next_time <= CURRENT_TIME))
```

A composite index on (next_date, date_end) should also help with performance but if you use EXPLAIN to check the execution plan it should help you decide on the most effective indexing. You should check with an index on (date_end, next_date) too. Without knowing more about the distribution of data it is impossible to say which one will help the most.

Comment: So I did what you avised. i added the index (next_date, date_end) but for some reason when I call EXPLAIN on the query you provided, it is not using the index that I created.  ..?

Comment: Did you try the index the other way around? You could try using [FORCE INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html) to try the indices to see what effect they have on the execution plan.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [explain](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/using-explain.html). It will tell you what is happening under the bonnet.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps look at using a datetime field instead of the two fields - this will cut out the unnecessary data conversion in the query.

```
SELECT id, name, title, description, time 
FROM entity 
WHERE NOW() BETWEEN (date_time_end AND date_time_next);
```

Don't think you'll get much better than that without partitioning the table based on dates.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should improve query performance a little bit without changing the DB schema.

```
SELECT id, name, title, description, time FROM entity 
WHERE NOW() BETWEEN ADDTIME(next_date, next_time) AND ADDTIME(date_end, time_end)
```

Actually, `BETWEEN` will compare with `>=` and `<=`. If you don't want it to be like that then keep the comparison with `>` and `<` instead of using `BETWEEN`.